# Passing result of mrjob step to next step as parameter

Tags: python, mapreduce, mrjob

I am writing a multi-step mrjob. The first step does some pre-processing and ends with the following reducer:

```
def some_reducer(self, key, values):
    values = (int (value) for value in values)
    if key == 'iwantthiskey':
        //I want to pass sum(values) as a parameter to the next step
```

I've tried going through the documentation and experimented with adding passthrough options or adding values to self.jobconf(), but I couldn't figure it out.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[Sonic provided an excellent solution by making a global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26155420/4257237). Basically, once you get the wanted value, store it in the global variable for later use.

```
my_parameter = None

def some_reducer(self, key, values):
  global my_parameter
  values = (int (value) for value in values)
  if key == 'iwantthiskey':
      my_parameter = sum(values)

def next_funtion_or_job(self, input, parameter=my_parameter):
  #Your method goes here.
```

````