# Multiple input files for each mapper 'type'

Tags: java, python, hadoop, mapreduce, mrjob

I am trying to run a job where each mapper 'type' recieves a different input file. I know there is a way to do this with Java using MultipleInputs class like so:

```
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job,new Path(args[0]),TextInputFormat.class,CounterMapper.class);
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job,new Path(args[1]),TextInputFormat.class,CountertwoMapper.class);
```

Where CounterMapper.class and CountertwoMapper.class are the respective mapper 'types'.

I am trying to achieve similar functionality with [MrJob](https://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/) for Python or any other language that is not Java (please don't ask why!).

This [image](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/--kQHhv6ZynA/UupiqicS3mI/AAAAAAAAAK4/7dzDRftUjkk/s640/xx.png) is similar to what I want to achieve.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps this answer can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302580/multiple-inputs-with-mrjob

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way in which different mappers can be associated to a sing input path, this doesn't exactly answer your question but hope it helps you. In the link below

[Using multiple mapper inputs in one streaming job on hadoop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180791/using-multiple-mapper-inputs-in-one-streaming-job-on-hadoop)